# How do I work with variables in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I set this up a while ago in something that is not really used.  I was under the impression that it worked at the time, but I'm trying to test it now and am getting some errors.

Here is my snowflake code:

```
var rs = snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: "select count(*) from toptal.stage_resellers" } ).execute();
rs.next();
var resellers = rs.getColumnValue(1);
```

I that that var resellers was going to define a variable that would have the number of rows in stage_resellers, but I'm not confident of that.

I decided to test it just by inserting the value into a logging table that I am using into an unused column for the time being.

Here is that code:

```
var stmt1 = snowflake.execute ( { sqlText:`insert into toptal.processing_executions values ('merge into dim_resellers', current_timestamp, 'processing', :resellers);`});
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Execution error in store procedure PROCESSING: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 110 Bind variable :resellers not set. At Snowflake.execute, line 47 position 24
```

I tried futzing around with setting the variable, to no avail.

I have a feeling that I am mixing up environments here, but I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: The `:name` form is for snowsql variables. Where-as the use of `snowflake.execute` implies javascript procedure.

Answer (score 1):

To execute:

```
var stmt1 = snowflake.execute ( { sqlText:`insert into toptal.processing_executions values ('merge into dim_resellers', current_timestamp, 'processing', :resellers);`});
```

variables has to be provided as `?` or `:1`. Code becomes:

```
var stmt1 = snowflake.execute({
      sqlText: `insert into toptal.processing_executions
                values ('merge into dim_resellers', current_timestamp,
                        'processing', ?)`
     ,binds: [resellers] } );
```

More at documentation: [Binding Variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript.html#binding-variables)